# PowerShell stuck in Constrained Language Mode

Tags: powershell, console, restriction

I'm a coding collage major, and I am using my school's computer to make a cross-platform script for Linux and Windows. I need to run the script to test it, but PowerShell keeps responding with "Cannot create type. Only core types are supported in this language mode." I cannot use admin, as this is not my computer. I really don't wanna restart on my home computer, and then I cannot work on it in class. Can anyone help?

I tried imputing`PS C:\Windows\System32> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'fulllanguage'`but it still did not work. PowerShell responded with `InvalidOperation: Cannot set property. Property setting is supported only on core types in this language mode.` When I boot up PowerShell, the starting text is

```
PowerShell 7.4.1
[Constrained Language Mode]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By security-minded design, **you cannot switch from a more restrictive PowerShell [language mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Modes) to a more permissive one *in-session***.

Therefore, executing `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'`, i.e. switching to *unrestricted* use of all language features  is *pointless*, because the command will only succeed if you're already in that language mode.<sup>[1]</sup>

If your PowerShell sessions are forced into `ConstrainedLanguage` mode by a [WDAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/application-control) or [AppLocker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview) policy, the only way to put them into `FullLanguage` mode is by changing the policy - which requires *elevation* (running with administrative privileges), so you may have to ask your IT department for assistance - assuming they're willing to allow you access to `FullLanguageMode`.

---

<sup>[1] There appears to be a limited exception, but I'm unclear on whether the behavior is intentional or not. PowerShell 7.4 introduced an *audit-only* `ConstrainedLanguage` mode that in effect *behaves* like `FullLanguage`, but *logs* as if `ConstrainedLanguage` mode were in effect. In this audit-only mode, `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'` apparently succeeds (which would disable the logging part) - see [GitHub issue #20768](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20768).</sup>

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding, but I really don't know what audit mode is, and all of this is new to me. I know that the command does not succeed, and all FullLanguage commands also do not succeed, so I don't think I am in audit mode. Sorry for the late response, I have a lot of homework, and thanks for responding at all.

Comment: @NathanKalusa, the audit-mode remark was just an aside, and doesn't apply to your case. The bottom line is that if one of the two policies mentioned in the answer are in place, you'll need to ask whoever has the power to change them so as to allow you to use `FullLanguage` mode - assuming they're willing  to do that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up, I will ask our IT guy to see if he can change it. Thank you for all your help. Have A great day!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm just new to this website as I usually use GitHub.